# Cannot import libraries from Node_Modules to ASP.NET CORE APP

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-5

I'm learning Scott Allen - ASP.Net Core Fundamental course from Pluralsight and trying to add the external library from Node_Modules to my project.

***Here is the project's structure:***

[image]

***And how I including datatable library to my project (adding to Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml)***
[image]

***But when the app is running, it cannot find these libraries:***
[image]

***Questions:***

1. What wrong with this way ?
2. Can you guys suggest some effective ways to import external libraries to ASP.NET CORE app?

***I'm using .NET 5***

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: You don't serve the contents of `node_modules` directly to website visitors. Instead your application's **build process** will run tools like Gulp, WebPack, Uglify, Rollup, etc which produce compact (minified) JS which will be in your `/scripts` or `/dist` folder to be served. (Of course integrating an npm build with MSBuild can be complicated).

Comment: The problem with the JavaScript developer ecosystem is that it's incredibly fast-moving - pretty much everything I learned even 2-3 years ago is irrelevant now (e.g. I knew AngularJS in 2015 but all that knowledge was obsolete when Angular2 came out; and everything I thought I knew about Grunt and Babel in 2017 is moot now - it's a lot of work to keep up, unfortunately)

Comment: Yeah, the technologies change so fast, need to keep learning and updating every day and cannot escape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the default directory that we store static files is `{content root}/wwwroot`, you can move these datatables plugin related js&css files to web root directory.

For more information about serving static files in ASP.NET Core, please check this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Thank you Fei Han, I solved my problem from your document.

Answer (score 0):

From the document provided by Fei Han I solved my problem. I need add some config to include "node_modules" as `PhysicalFileProvider` in Startup.cs file like below:
[image]

and then update `src` and `href` attribute in script/link tag:

```
<script src="~/StaticFiles/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="~/StaticFiles/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```